# How to terminate a server socket thread on timeout?

Tags: java, spring, sockets, spring-integration

I'm using `Spring Integration` on the server side to offer a socket. The socket as a defined `soTimeout`, so that exceeding that timeout will close the current open socket connection to the client.

```
TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean fact = new TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean();
fact.setSoTimeout(timeout);
```

But the thread on the server side will continue. How can I force cancelation/termination of the server socket as well (maybe with an additional thread timeout, so that no thread can hang in the background by any issues)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you mean you want to stop listening for new connections when one of the client connenctions times out.

Implement `ApplicationListener` for `TcpConnectionExceptionEvent` and examine the exception; if it's a `SocketTimeoutException`, call `close()` on the server factory that was created by the factory bean.